# iOS extension: how to run a share extension in Safari under debug mode?

Tags: mobile-safari, ios8

I'v made a share extension, and it did appear in Safari's share extensions list, but when I use Xcode and run the extension scheme, I can't choose Safari as a host app for my extension(Safari is not in the list).

What should I configure so that I can test my extension using Safari as a host app?

Answer (score -2):

Actually, you don't have to choose Safari as host. I tried other apps as host, it worked as well.

Hopefully this helps.